# Java If else nested. public static void ()

Tags: java, if-statement, static, void

My school task is to make a program with the price of sending a letter: input grams, output price. but i get this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B422s.png

Comment: Might have forgotten some things. Like the error message. And your code.

Comment: Post your code and stacktrace.

Comment: A picture of your code is not your code.  Please take the time to [edit] your question to add the code as text.

Comment: Post your code and error, not a picture of them.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy, paste, and format your actual code directly here. Looks like you don't have a class to contain your method. Pick up a basic java tutorial. Did you read the error message? Did you google it?

Comment: Read what the compiler says, looks obvious to me closing parenthesis are missing.

Comment: You need a class.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your program.

 1. Main method has to be `public static void main(String[] args)
 2. Class name is incorrect. Java is a case sensitive language. `scanner` and `Scanner` both are not same. Use `Scanner` instead of `scanner`.
 3. Instead of `system.in` use `System.in`.

Before writing any code you should at least go thru the [documentation/tutorials][1] available online to understand language.


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your main signature is wrong, it's public static void main(String args[]) {...}, also you missed the class definition, system.in is a static call, so should be Capitalized, man, your code has lots of typos

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main()` is not the correct method to make an execution class.

Second, `Scanner` class should be capitalized.

Comment: I got it, and fixed the rest. now I have no syntax error. Thanks many times